# Prove that white noise + normality = independence

Tags: time-series, normal-distribution, arima, independence, white-noise

If the time series process is linear, then the ARIMA model is specified.
The residuals from this model are $(1.)$ no autocorrelation $(2.)$ mean equals zero $(3.)$ constant variance. We say that this process is a white noise process. But under white Gaussian noise, how to proof no autocorrelation = independent? And how to proof the white noise from Gaussian distribution?

Comment: Gaussian distribution does not imply white noise, so you cannot prove that.

Answer (score 0):

No autocorrelation is not independent. To statistically check if the given time series is autocorrelated you can use Ljung-Box-Test, there is also many other test that have the same target. You can also plot the histogram, the Q-Q-Normal, and the Residuals vs Predicted graph, with those you can visually check if the residuals follow a normal distribution or not.